# Codeigniter lost session when cross controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created a Facebook login on my site, then when I get data of a user logged, I created an array session to store the information of users in my controller.

I have problem with this session when I go to another page, my session gets lost, I don't know what happens with this?

I set the session like this: `$this->session->set_userdata('fb_user_info', $user_info);`

But, my own account login, I do the same way, it works on all pages.

My question is, Why does the session get lost?

Here is my code to set session when get user_info

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Account extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{       
    parent::__construct();
    //$this->authenticate();

    // Facebook constructor code
        $CI = & get_instance();
        $CI->config->load("facebook",TRUE);
        $config = $CI->config->item('facebook');
        $this->load->library('facebook', $config); 
    public function index() 
    {       
        $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

        if($user) {

            try {

                $user_info = $this->facebook->api('/me');

        // Set session

            $this->session->set_userdata('FB_SESSION_INFO', $user_info);

                    $args = $logout_url;

            $data['getLogoutUrl'] = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl($args);

        } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
                echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
                $user = null;
            }
        } else {

            $param = array('scope' => 'email','redirect_uri' => $mycurrent_url);

            $data['getURLLogin'] = "<a href=\"".$this->facebook->getLoginUrl($param)."\">Login with facebook</a>";

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you loading session library in your constructor? $this->load->library('session');

Comment: If your session is get lost in another controlelr it means the session is not available there... initialize your session in the constructor of your main controlelr so it is visible in every controller

Comment: I was loaded in autoload.php in config folder alread!

Comment: just try to echo the session data in the controller where it is lost and see the result

Comment: lost session, when different controller file.

Comment: please provide me some code of all the files where you set session, where the session is visible and where it is lost... then I will have a better idea...

Comment: But, I wonder, why my own session account login page, don't lost, and
session facebook data lost?

Comment: Session is browser dependent if you close the the page and open it again your session will be lost...

Comment: Can you please load your session library in the constructor of your account controller and I assume that all the rest of the controller extends account controller... Just remove it form autoload.php and include it here

Comment: just use session in database o.o

Comment: Oh, I found the problem!, Codeigniter need slash (/) at the end of the url structure,

when I logged facebook app success, I try to put (/) at the end of facebook redirect_uri, and I click back to home page my session is working, So, I don't know what's wrong with the Server side, for my local working no need to put (/) at the end of the url.

Any idea please!

Comment: Do you have firebug installed? maybe you could look in these thread
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/222443/

Comment: What is the name of your session Cookie?
Browsers don't work very well when cookie name has underscores and thats the codeigniter standard.

Also, make sure that the information you set in the session is smaller than 4kb, since that is the max size a single cookie can have.

If the information you need stored in the session is larger, you should switch to storing the session in the database, you can find instructions on how to do that in the codeigniter manual.